# Jenkins Build when a particular git branch changes

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, post-update

I am using the git plugin for jenkins.  It works well, except that it rebuilds my targets any time ANY of the branches are changed on the given project.  What I need it to do is rebuild ONLY IF a particular branch has been changed.  Is there a way to do this?  Right now I am using git hooks and the notifyCommit option with the plugin.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `Source Code Management` you can set the `Branches to build` field to your desired branch.

Comment: Yes, but it still builds when I change other branches.

Comment: What format did you use? Personally, I just use `BRANCH` which should be shorthand for `*/BRANCH` and it works fine. I'm definitely not fully up to date on plugins or Jenkins though.

Comment: That shouldn't be any different than a job kicked off by a polling schedule. I was referring to the format of the `Branches to build` field. Which fix did you use for `UnknownHostKey` error? I haven't tested versions past 1.1.26 and it's unclear from those bugs whether the `GIT_BRANCH` env variable might be ignored in 1.2.0 and 1.3.0.

Comment: For the unknownhostkey error, checkout out this:  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17204                     Its the comment on 14/Mar/13 2:53 AM

Comment: Do that, then do sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart